# Nothing happens when script is run

Tags: python, scripting

Several questions similar to mine...with no answers. 
Enter a line in the text editor, Run Script...nothing or "see console"

Code example:

`print(2+2)` or `bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.002'].location=(50,0,0)`

Enter same line in the console, OK.
Can paste several lines into text editor, but no paste option to console.

The manual and the tutorials suggests what I'm doing should work, but I see a few others seem to be having problems too.

Comment: Please give an example of what code you are trying to run.

Comment: The "see console" is about the system console, not the python console. You can make it appear with the "Window / Toggle system console" menu. Be aware that if you close the system console window directly, it will also close Blender.

Comment: Use ctrl-C and ctrl-V to cut and paste in blenders python console.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  Difficult to understand how I read the into and watched the tutorial and didn't spot the distinction between the Python console and the system console.